# Creating Library Results in The method getDecorView() is undefined for the type & The method getWindow() is undefined for the type

Tags: java, android, android-library

I'm attempting to create a library which hide the navigation bar and action bar (I know this is a hackish way of doing things - but it will only be on one version of Android and one specific device model - so it should be fine - we don't need global compatibility - we just need it to work)

The problem - is I'm getting a few error when creating the library stating:

```
The method getDecorView() is undefined for the type  &  The method getWindow() is undefined for the type
```

as well as

```
Return type for the method is missing & Syntax error on token ".", { expected.
```

I've attempted to add:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
```

as suggested by another SO article - however I must not be implementing it correctly.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

### Source:

```
public class HideNav{



    // Hide Android Navigation bar
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(8);

    // Hide Android Status Bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}
}
```

### Errors:

```
Syntax error on token ".", { expected   
The method getDecorView() is undefined for the type 
The method getWindow() is undefined for the type 
Return type for the method is missing   





DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

### Edit:

I've attempted to implement the suggestion in the comments below by using:

```
public class HideNav extends View{
    public HideNav(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void changeSomethingInWindow(){
        // get a reference of the activity
        Activity parent = (Activity)getContext();
        // using the activity, get Window reference
        Window window = parent.getWindow();
        // using the reference of the window, do whatever you want :D
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}



combined with:


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         HideNav view = new HideNav(this);
            view.changeSomethingInWindow(); 
            setContentView(view);
```

However I'm getting

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.hidenav.HideNav at onCreate(ActivityMain.java:100)
```

which is:

```
MaskUI view = new MaskUI(this);
```

Comment: your statements are outside of any method. Are you sure that is the way you coded. Also is it a activity class or normal java class

Comment: Just a java class - I have another class which extends Activity and has the layout included - I just need to create a library I can import to hide the Navigation and Action Bar (and I'm not sure exactly how this should be coded - it's my first time creating a library)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow()

Comment: I attempted your solution - can you take a look at the source above? I'm getting a fatal exception when attempting to do so.

Comment: More information can be found here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170911/attempting-to-create-library-results-in-fatal-exception